# Novice question: what values of $x$ satisfy $\frac{x^2}{x} \le 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Okay I'm embarrassed to even ask this clearly I am not going to win a Nobel prize in my life.

**Question**

What values of $x$ satisfy:

$$\frac{x^2}{x} \le 0 $$

**My attempt**

I'm very tempted to simplify the LHS and say the answer is $x \le 0$

But I have this  nagging concern that the answer is actually $x<0$

If I start from the other direction, then I have

$$x \le 0$$

$$x*1 \le 0*1$$

$$x\frac{x}{x} \le 0 \frac{x}{x}$$

And the last line only holds if $x$ is not zero and therefore it changes to

$$x\frac{x}{x} < 0 \frac{x}{x}$$

$$\frac{x^2}{x} < 0 $$

And now that there is no threat of dividing by zero I can reduce it to $x<0$

Is this right?

I feel like in general when doing math I multiply top and bottom by $x$ all the time and I never really think about explicitly calling out that $x$ can't be zero.

Thanks for your help/patience.

Comment: People can certainly improve throughout their life. But I have a suspicion you won't get a Nobel prize in math.

Comment: @mathworker21 I don't think there is a Nobel prize in math.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. In general when you have $5x = 15$ can you do $5x \frac{x}{x} = 15 \frac{x}{x} $ so $x=3$ and $x \ne 0$ therefore $x=3$. I know that is kind of ridiculous but is it the right thinking?

Comment: It is confusing because the inequality, $$\frac{x^2}{x}\leqslant 0$$ is incorrect since division by $0$ is impossible, and $\dfrac{x^2}{x} = x^{2-1} = x$.

Comment: @user477343 Interesting... so the values of $x$ that "satisfy" the inequality are $x<0$ but you are right you will never "fully satisfy" the original inequality since you can't get $0$ to do the full "$\le$"... is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @valer https://imgur.com/gallery/utzTCyo

Comment: @HJ_beginner yes. This proves that if $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{x}$, it does not necessarily mean that $f(x) = x$. In this case, we just have an inequality.

Comment: @valer that's the point

Comment: @user477343 Thanks that is a good way of putting it.

Comment: @valer @ mathworker I stand corrected I will not win a Fields medal. I also won't win a Nobel either. Honestly I don't think I'm going to win anything in life except death and freedom from the 3 lbs of fat I'm trapped in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x=0$, $\frac{x^2}{x}$ is undefined.

If $x>0$, $\frac{x^2}{x}=x >0$.

If $x<0$, $\frac{x^2}{x} = x<0$.

Hence the answer is $x<0$.

Comment: Thanks Siong as always you are the man. In general when you have $5x = 15$ can you do $5x \frac{x}{x} = 15 \frac{x}{x} $ so $x=3$ and $x \ne 0$ therefore $x=3$. I know that is kind of ridiculous but is it the right thinking?

Comment: If $5x=15$, I don't see how multiply and divide by $x$ helps,I would just divide both sides by $5$ and conclude that $x=\frac{15}3=5$.

Comment: Yeah I agree that multiplying by $\frac{x}{x}$ is ridiculous... I'm just trying to solidify the rules in my head.

Comment: You can do that after you check that $x \ne 0$. but yup, doesn't seem to simplify it though it is alright to do so.

Comment: Yes I'm thinking since $x \ne 0$ and $x = 3$ these two statements reduce to $x=3$

Answer (score 3):

The top is always non-negative, so you need the bottom to be purely negative to make the whole thing less than $0$.  Hence $x <0$.

Note that having it equal to $0$ is out of the question because this could only occur when the top is $0$ but the bottom isn't, which is impossible because the top is $0$ only when the bottom is.

Comment: Ahhh I was so caught up in solving the problem by manipulating things that I forgot about just looking at the problem. Thanks that helps a lot!

Comment: We've all been there.

Comment: In general when you have $5x = 15$ can you do $5x \frac{x}{x} = 15 \frac{x}{x} $ so $x=3$ and $x \ne 0$ therefore $x=3$. I know that is kind of ridiculous but is it the right thinking as I'm trying to solidify the rules of when you can multiply top and bottom by $x$.

Answer (score 2):

For

$$\frac{x^2}{x} \le 0 $$

we need $x\neq0$ then numerator is always positive and the sign depends by the denominator then

$$\frac{x^2}{x} < 0 \iff x< 0$$

and never $\frac{x^2}{x} =0 $.

Comment: Appreciate it. I think for novices like me it's just so tempting to simply the LHS to $x$ and I couldn't articulate in my head why that is a no no.

Comment: I can add a solution by simplification explaining when and how it can be done, if useful.

Comment: Can you help me with another thought experiment. If you have $5x = 15$ can you do $5x \frac{x}{x} = 15 \frac{x}{x} $ so $x=3$ and $x \ne 0$ therefore these two statements about $x$ become one, namely $x=3$. I know that is a strange thing to do but I'm trying to solidify the rules of multiplying top and bottom by $x$.

Comment: I don’t understand your step, of course the thing to fo here is $5x=15\iff \frac55x=\frac{15}5$.

Comment: Yes I agree it's a bizarre thing to do and nobody would do it. But I believe it is technically legal... and I was just trying to square in my head how introducing $\frac{x}{x}$ into an equation works for a simple example.

Comment: For you inequality you csn indeed condider $$\frac{x^2}{x} =\frac{x}{x} x\le 0 $$ and for $x\neq 0$ we have $\frac{x}{x}=1$ and then $\frac{x}{x} x\le 0\implies x<0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help gimusi that helps. You are doing the Lord's work.